# what does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0

When I try to use a random number the error below appears, so how can I modify the code with another method?

minSdkVersion 19

targetSdkVersion 28

```
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method double java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextDouble(double, double) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
   Before Android 4.1, method int java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextInt(int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
   Before Android 4.1, method long java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextLong(long, long) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
```

java code

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(16 - 6) + 6;
long maxTimeInMilliseconds = (i * 1000);
startTimer(maxTimeInMilliseconds, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error, but a warning. You can ignore it, since both your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` target a higher Android version than the one this warning is about.

It's basically just telling you: *"Hey, be aware, if you change your SDK version to 15 or lower, this code will misbehave."*